# landlord asking other tenants to spy on each other

Tags: tenant, human-rights

We recently got a new property management company. She is evicting people at an alarming rate and asking for deposits for pets that were waived by our previous prop mgmt and wanting to see our apartments so that they can access damages so they can deduct them from our paid deposits. She seemed to have information about tenants that seemed odd; like she could see into apartments. I am no accusing her of that!!! We, meaning me and other tenants, have discovered that she is asking tenants to report on what they know about certain tenants. If someone has a pet, or how many people are living in the unit, questions about their visitors, etc. She even asked a tenant to keep their eyes and ears open to find out who the target and offender was in a drive by shooting. Most of them don't want to comply but are afraid that if they don't they might be evicted. Is she allowed to do this??

Comment: Based on the available info, it doesn't *sound* like there is anything wrong with what she is doing other than, perhaps, being overly heavy-handed with her requests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, she is allowed to ask: each tenant if free to comply or refuse to comply.

She can only evict tenants in compliance with their lease and local law - I doubt either mentions refusing to spy on their neighbours as grounds for eviction.